# Cannot find plugin "karma-jasmine"

Tags: angularjs

when i run `karma start` i face with this errors

```
31 12 2015 09:59:40.923:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-jasmine".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
31 12 2015 09:59:40.934:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-phantomjs-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
      ^

Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
```

clearly it complains because it does not have `karma-jasmin`
and i run this command

```
sudo npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

to make sure it is installed, and in response it gives me this message

```
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No README data
karma-jasmine@0.3.6 node_modules/karma-jasmine.
```

I mean, it seems to me that karma-jasmin is installed.
and then i tried

```
sudo npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

The problem is, i expect that after these two commands i can run `karma start`
but again it complains that, `cannot find plugin "karma-jasmin"`

update:
i have this in my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

it seems to me that the solution was in

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Comment: This worked for me AFTER I had already installed --save-dev all the required plugin packages; karma-cli is apparently the command line tools and karma is itself just a runner. Thanks!